# How to properly size radiobuttons in radiogroup?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

**EDIT**: As a test I've been using fixed sizes for the radio buttons and backgrounds:

> android:layout_height="40dp"
>   android:layout_width="40dp"

The result is an overflow to the left, obviously.
[image]

---

I'm using a GridLayout that contains radioGroups that spans all the columns of my grid.
I would like to make all radioButtons sized equally and take all the place available.

You can see that the radio group (selected in the Visual Studio for Mac designer) is taking all the available space in the following picture, but not the buttons:

[image]

Each radio button is a custom one, it displays a number between 1 and 10 and is circled with color when selected.

Here is the axml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:columnCount="10" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_radio_group" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="1" android:tag="1" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="2" android:tag="2" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="3" android:tag="3" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="4" android:tag="4" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="5" android:tag="5" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="6" android:tag="6" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="7" android:tag="7" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="8" android:tag="8" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score9" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="9" android:tag="9" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score10" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="10" android:tag="10" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </GridLayout>
```

And the drawables:

> qol_score_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/b"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/a"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/a"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/b" />
</selector>
```

> a.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="#fff" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#53aade" />
    </shape>
```

> b.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="#fff" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#555555" />
    </shape>
```

I have to say that I'm having a hard time with sizing elements. Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you try first by giving fixed widht and height in place of wrapcontent and check whether there is any change or not.

Comment: The radio disappears

Comment: try giving fixed size to `android:layout_height=”40dp”
android:layout_width=”40dp”` to your shape in `a.xml` and `b.xml`

Comment: Still no change

Comment: can you update the question with those changes.

Comment: With fixed sizes for both the radio buttons and the backgroud, I have something that now overflows on the right. This is why I do not want to set fixed sizes in the first place

Comment: can you update the answer as to know how it looks.

Comment: Try setting following propertes of each radio button with values I have specified and check.  `android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" `

Comment: if I remember correctly radio groups support weights and this will work.

Comment: You are right, you could add your answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Radio-Group` allows child with weights, setting following properties to each child `Radio-Button` will set width of each child equally.

```
<RadioButton 
android:id="@+id/my_rad_1" 
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background"
android:button="@android:color/transparent" 
android:checked="false" 
android:text="1" 
android:tag="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of solving this issue would be using the AppCompat `RadioButton`instead:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 .
 .
 . />
```

After adding this the issue should not happen in case it still does kindly revert.

Comment: Still the same issue with this change

Comment: can you try removing the background and trying after that and see how it looks ?

Comment: again, no change.